# Split Data Frame into New Dataframe for each consecutive Column

Tags: python, dataframe

Looking to split columns of this data frame into multiple data frames. Each with the date column and the consecutive column. How do I get a function that can automate this. So we would have n data frames, n being the number of columns in the original data frame - 1( the date column).

[image]

Comment: You can first use a list to append all the dataframe with splitted column: `[df[['Date', i+1]] for i in range(len(df.columns))]`. Then you assign it to new dataframes or save it to new file.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing first is to set the date column as the index:

`df.set_index('Date')`

Then, when you filter the data frame by a single column you will get a series object with the date and your column of interest:

e.g. `df.P19245Y8E` will give a series of the second column.

I think this will do what you need, but if you really want to create separate dataframes for each column then you just iterate through the columns:

```
new_dfs = []
for col in df.columns:
    new_dfs.append(df[col])
```

or with list comprehension:

`new_dfs = [df[col] for col in df.columns]`